# Ansible массовая рассылка ssh ключей

Tags: ssh, ansible

внезапно появилась задача управления парком постоянно растущего числа машин с astra linux,на текущий момент 170+ был выбран ansible, пароль суперпользователя везде одинаков. Как я понял есть два варианта доступа через ssh при помощи связки ключей, либо по паролю. Отсюда и вопрос, как массово можно разбросать свой ключик по хостам? либо в этом нет необходимости и достаточно запустить плейбук с ключем -u (учетка) --ask-pass и он будет применен ко всем машинам в списке (пароль суперпользователя везде одинаков) или же придется вводить пароль условные 100 раз?

Comment: А зачем вводить пароль, если есть `group_vars/all` и `ansible_user` с `ansible_password`?

Answer (score 0):

Скопируйте свой ключ (подставьте в пример путь до своего актуального - мы же не знаем, что за ключ вы используете у себя) на все 170+ хостов.
Что вам посоветовать: сначала пройдитесь по хостам и пропишите их у себя, чтобы избежать лишних вопросов про fingerprint:

`ssh-keyscan hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Затем скопируйте свой на каждый ("yes" здесь на всякий случай, если первая команда кое-где не прошла):

`echo "yes \n" | ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@hostname`

Можете обернуть в цикл, типа такого (создайте список хостов заранее в hosts.list):

`` for i in `cat /tmp/hosts.list | sort | uniq`; do ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@$i;done ``